# Git diff without the pluses and minuses

Tags: git, diff, git-diff

Is there a git way of outputting a diff without the pluses and minuses on the beginning of each line? (of course relying only on the color to indicate the operation)

I tried using sed to remove them but it's not ideal.

Comment: Why don't you use GUI tools like kdiff, TortoiseGitMerge?

Answer (score 3):

```
git diff --word-diff=color
```

will only show diffs using color. However, the format is different than a line-wise unified diff.